# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
height_feet = int(input("Enter portion of height in feet "))
height_inch = int(input("Enter portion of heigh in inches"))
height_in_inch = height_feet * 12 + height_inch
height_in_cm = height_in_inch * 2.54
print (height_in_cm)

Enter portion of height in feet 6
Enter portion of heigh in inches1.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled.py", line 2, in <module>
    height_inch = int(input("Enter portion of heigh in inches"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.5'
>>>
```

I'm brand new to python and I don't understand why it displays this error when I try to multiply by something with a decimal

Comment: You are looking for `float` not `int` (for the inches measurement). An integer is a number that can be written without a fraction. 1.5 cannot be written without a fraction.

Comment: You can't cast the string of a non-integer to an integer. 1.5 isn't an integer so it throws that error. Try using `float` instead

Comment: @PeterWang Python has no *casts*. Calling `int` will *parse* the string and obtain an `int` value. Casting is an operation used in *statically* typed languages where you basically tell the compiler to treat that value as if it was of an other type. sometimes it requires small changes to the value (e.g. adding padding `0`s) but surely not something like parsing a decimal literal.

Comment: @Bakuriu wow-- I mistakenly use the term pretty freely, so thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 1):

change to : `int(float(input("Enter portion of heigh in inches")))`

`str` to `float` to `int` should work if `str` is something like `1.333`

`str` to int only works when `str` is an integer like `4`

Answer (score 0):

This should be a `float` type, not an `int` type.

Answer (score 0):

In Python and elsewhere, ints are only *whole* numbers. 1.5, 1.2, pi, anything with a decimal is not an int. You want `float` to describe them. It's short for floating point number.